# How to output a "\"" (double quotation mark) from lua to console?

Tags: redis, lua

I am trying to output a piece of contacted string from Lua to Console. The string has a double quotation mark automatically at the front and at the back of itself when it is shown in the console. I would like to have some other double quotation marks in the middle of the string, but I cannot do that.

I have tried several different methods as I show in the comments below, but none of these work. The output is usually something like:

```
1) "10000\": \"1543412332"
2) "10001\": \"1543233731"
3) "10003\": \"1543637245"
4) "10004\": \"1543227124"
5) "10005\": \"1543226828"
```

But I want the output to be:

```
1) "10000": "1543412332"
2) "10001": "1543233731"
3) "10003": "1543637245"
4) "10004": "1543227124"
5) "10005": "1543226828"
```

Here is my code

```
    for index = 1, table.maxn(resultKey) do
       local unconcatted = {[1] = resultKey[index], [2] = [[": "]], [3] = resultValue[index]}
    -- local unconcatted = {[1] = "\"", [2] = resultKey[index], [3] = "\": \"", [4] = resultValue[index], [5] = "\""}
    -- local unconcatted = {[1] = resultKey[index], [2] = "\": \"", [3] = resultValue[index]}
    -- local unconcatted = {[1] = resultKey[index], [2] = '\": \"', [3] = resultValue[index]}
       local concatted = table.concat(unconcatted);
       table.insert(resultFinal, 1, concatted);
    end
return resultFinal;
```

Comment: You could also try to replace `\"` with `%"` or using the char function (`string.char(34)`).

Comment: It's not clear where the problem is here. You've shown things, but none of them produce the output you say they produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To escape one kind of quotes, use another one!

```
"'" = single quote literal
'"' = double quote literal
[['"']] = string within [[]] is parsed as is (dropping leading newlines if there are any)
[=[I have [[ and ]] inside!]=] = Use `=` when you need [[]] inside, add more `=` if required
```

In your case

```
local unconcatted = {'"', resultKey[index], '": "', resultValue[index], '"'}
```

should do the job. You can replace `'` pairs with `[[` and `]]` if you prefer.

Also note that I've dropped indexes. It's preferred notation when you need to just have an array and does same thing as what you had before, freeing you from keeping numeration on changes and potentially improving performance.

Your `for` loop isn't really good. `table.maxn` is deprecated in Lua 5.1 and is removed in later versions. You should either use new syntax for length:

```
for index = 1, #resultKey do
end
```

or use `ipairs`:

```
for index,key in ipairs(resultKey) do
    local unconcatted = {'"', key, '": "', resultValue[index], '"'}
    …
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your additional advices are very helpful!

Comment: @GlenXoseph If my answer turned out to be useful, consider marking it as right solution (by clicking onto green check left to the answer) and upvoting once you have enough reputation. It's generally discouraged to use "Thank you" comments on StackOverflow/StackExchange. It worth nothing to carefully read "tour" page once.